# fast download xml file from server python

Tags: php, python, xml

Im downloading big database of phishing/virus sites from clean-mx

phishing database = http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/xmlphishing.php

virus database = http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/xmlviruses.php

Now the problem is that those xml files size is about +30Mb for each, and It takes about 1 minute to download them and I need to download them faster...
I download them by using `urllib.urlretrieve`.

I need those files to build xml database that contains the urls inside those databases, I've tried to read them, hoping that it should be faster than donwload them, with `urllib.urlopen` but it even slower then download them.

Do you have an Idea to use those files (download or read) to build my database with faster performance?

Note: Just need to use those files, I already write code that build my database fast

Comment: The site you mention requires a login, so there is no way others can test the download speed. Do you get faster downloads in a web browser, or via command-line tools such as `wget` or `curl`? It could be that the server simply throttles download speed.

Comment: You dont need to login, I download this files without login the site...look at  http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/viruses.php and http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/phishing.php I just add xml and the sites return xml output (look at the line " Same query as xml output")
also I've tried via wget and its the same as `urllib.urlretrieve`

Comment: Why do you need to download them faster? Downloading once should be enough (depending on your usecase). Maybe there is another way instead of downloading the file often?

Comment: Every hour I delete them and download them again for updates (every half hour they update the databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried downloading the virus XML via Firefox in OS X and Linux (running in a VM), and using the excellent [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) module (which I much prefer over `urllib`), and all methods took a very long time to download the 47M file - in fact, some processes froze or crashed. I have a 60 Mbit/s internet connection, and downloading a similar-sized file from an unthrottled server would only usually take 10-15s. So, I suspect that your results won't improve much, as it seems to be a server issue. I'd recommend contacting the owners of the website and seeing if they'd be willing to work with you to diagnose the connectivity issues.

**EDIT**

OK, this is weird. I restarted my Linux VM and ran the following in Terminal:

```
import requests
url = "http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/xmlviruses.php?"
r = requests.get(url).content
print(r)
```

The download finished in less than 15s. So, I'm not sure at all what's going on...

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly now! you right about requests...they have some magic in their module Thank You !!

Comment: @johndoe_asking Not sure *why* it works, but I'm glad you got it to work!